# CloudKit fetchRecordWithID error: "Fetching asset failed"

Tags: ios, fetch, cloudkit

I am trying to fetch a record with CloudKit and it fails with the following error: "Fetching asset failed" I confirmed (via the CloudKit Dashboard) that the record exists in my public database and the default zone and the default container (not a custom container). Here is my code:

```
CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];
CKRecordID *artworkRecordID = [[CKRecordID alloc] initWithRecordName:@"1C0DCC08-71D3-4C47-A417-DB92D2EECB67"];
[publicDatabase fetchRecordWithID:artworkRecordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord *artworkRecord, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Error handling for failed fetch from public database
    }
    else {
        // Display the fetched record
    }
}];
```

Comment: is that the error you get inside the completionHandler? or is it a fatal error? What is the complete error message? A CloudKit error usually also returns an error code.

Comment: The error is inside the completionHandler the error is a CKErrorDomain - code: 4 . But for a more info, here is a screen shot of the error in the debugger with the error expanded: [Screen Shot](http://screencast.com/t/YB7e9i6IzpF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in your screenshot the error code is 4 which is a network error

See xcdoc://?url=developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_constants/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CKErrorCode

Try switching to 3G or WiFi to see if there is different behavior.
If you go to your app settings, is mobile data enabled?
Can you run the code from the simulator?

Comment: That did it! The fetch was a part of using CloudKit notifications. I have my app on two devices -- an iPad and an iPhone. I save an image to iCloud via CloudKit on a Wi-Fi enabled iPad and do a fetch on my iPhone. This is where the above networking error occurs. So I switched the iPhone (notification receiving side) to using my cellar network instead of Wi-Fi and it works now! Thanks Edwin!

Answer (score 3):

I had a user get this because they weren’t signed in to iCloud in their iPhone Settings.